# Less cascading & refactoring

Tags: css, less

I am trying to refactor some css looking like this:

```
    path.myClass {
       //some CSS
    }
    .someOtherClass.myClass {
      //some other CSS
    }
```

I am struggling to find the right syntax for the first part. I am trying to have something looking like this:

```
.myClass {
   path.& {
      // some CSS
   }
   .someOtherClass {
      // some other CSS
   }
}
```

How can I refactor this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below. Since the top level selector already has `.` there is no need to add it again before the parent selector (`&`) in the inner selector. The second one is fairly straightforward as you can append the parent selector either at the start or at the end. The order of classes doesn't matter.

(*Note: There should be no space before the parent selector as it would change the meaning.*)

```
.myClass {
  path&{
    color: red;
  }
  .someOtherClass& { /* can do &.someOtherClass also, order doesn't matter */
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Below is the compiled CSS output:

```
path.myClass {
  color: red;
}
.someOtherClass.myClass {
  color: blue;
}
```